# Revert an incorrect merge

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

I have a similar issue to [“Duplicate” question's answers merged into wrong question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53349/158004). The difference here is that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965818/418413) is clearly nonsequitur under the supposed original. So much so that I think it demonstrates precisely in what way the questions are *not* duplicates.

How can the merge/dupe be reverted? (If it absolutely cannot be, at least consider this a feature request for more clearly marking merged answers.)

(I'm not trying to be ironic here and ask a duplication question about a dupe. There is no clear better way to make the case for and petition for a reversal than posting about it in meta-.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to adapt your answer to the question. If you can't - say, because the questions were not at all duplicates - then flag for moderator attention and request a review.

It's preferable for moderators to avoid merging when answers don't fit well on the destination, but in cases where they just need a bit of cleanup merging and then leaving a few comments for the answer-authors will suffice.

If a moderator becomes convinced that a merge was inappropriate, they can ask one of us (SE team) to help unmerge / clean up the mess. This is - and should be - extremely rare.